# JQuery Mobile Popup Does Not Display

Tags: ajax, xml, jquery-mobile, popup

I am pulling information from an XML document, one of the pieces of information is a city. When it displays the city I want the text of the city name to be a link for a popup which displays a link to the cities website. I have it so that the city is showing as a link.. but when I click it nothing happens.

Here is my code for pulling the information from xml..

```
function parseXML(xml) {
            $(xml).find('flight').each(function () {
                $("#F"+n).html("<span id = 'FC"+n+"'></span>"+
                    "<br />Country: "+ $(this).find("country").text() +
                    "<br />Description: "+ $(this).find("description").text() +
                    "<br />Airline: "+ $(this).find("airline").text() +
                    "<br />Flight Time: "+ $(this).find("flighttime").text() +
                    "<br />Flight Cost: " + $(this).find("flightcost").text());
                $("#FC" + n).html("City: <a href='#pop" + n + "' data-rel='popup' data-transition='pop'>" + $(this).find("city").text() +
                    "</a>");
                n++;
            });
```

and here is my div I want to use as a popup..

```
 <div id="pop0" data-role="popup">
    <p><a href="halifax.ca" target="_blank">Halifax's Website</a></p>
</div>
```

When I mouse over the city name, it has "/#pop0" at the end of the link so I don't know why it's not working

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Are you also adding the popup div dynamically? Where in the DOM is the popup DIV located? it must be within the same data-role="page" and if you add it dynamically make sure to initialize the widget ($("#pop0").popup())

Comment: @ezanker Yes! My issue was the I needed to make the popup div below the div where I wanted to activate the popup. Before I had it further down the document.